# Removing Common data from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, Dataframe 1 have 4 columns (A,B,C,D) with 20 rows and Dataframe 2 have same column headers as Dataframe 1 with 25 rows where first 20 rows are same as dataframe 1's 20 rows.

I want to Fetch the Dataframe 2's Unique 5 rows. and the fetching of those 5 rows should be done on index column.

Things that i've tried :

- I have tried the left outer join merge (it works but isn't efficient much)
- also tried the concatenation of two dataframes and then dropping the duplicates (it works only for 50% cases)
- also researched about the subtraction method but didn't understand anything

Kindly Help me through this problem,
Thank you.

Edit:

Dataframe 1 :

| Date | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| 11-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |

Dataframe 2 :

| Date | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| 11-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| 21-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 25-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |

I want the data which is unique which means this data :
Result Dataframe :

| Date | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 25-2-2020 | rowdata | row data | row_data |

and sometimes some data can be different in rows of both dataframe with same date index, but i don't care about that data all i want is above result dataframe

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community Added the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following for a complete diff between the two dataframes:

```
# complete diff between two dfs
df = pd.concat([one_df, two_df])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
df.reindex(idx)
```